# Export Eclipse NAT Table to CSV/Excel

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, export, nattable

I am currently working on a project that uses a nat table to display data to a user. I am wanting to add an option to export this nat table to a csv file or an excel document. Is there an easy way to export to excel or must I find a way to do it manually? If I must do it "the hard way" can anyone point me somewhere to help me get started on exporting to Excel?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for reading / writing to excel you can use Apache POI http://poi.apache.org/

for how to get started with Apache POI look at http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-read-write-excel-file-apache-poi/ might help

Comment: Thank you, this will do what I want.

Answer (score 1):

NatTable itself comes with a default exporter to Excel.

The exporter class is `ExcelExporter` (in package *org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.export.excel*).

An easy way to use this would be with `ExportCommand` (in package *org.eclipse.nebula.widgets.nattable.export.command*). With the default bindings, this results in a file chooser in which the user can specify a *.xls file.

```
ExportCommand cmd = new ExportCommand( m_table.getConfigRegistry(), m_table.getShell());
m_table.doCommand( cmd );
```

With version NatTable 0.9 on my system, when opening the file, Excel shows a warning that the file is in a different format than specified by the file extension.

Comment: Does this allow to open the workbook directly without saving it first?

Comment: This exports to a file, which can then be opened manually in Excel. It doesn't launch Excel automatically.

Comment: Alright. I currently implemented what Mehul recommended which basically does the same thing this does. I'm guessing doing it this way would cut down on dependencies needed. Think this would be more efficient?

Comment: If I were starting from scratch, I would start with the implementation that required the least amount of work. If you've already implemented something that works, and you're happy with it, it's reasonable to keep it. The Apache implementation may have additional benefits - e.g., see my note about the Excel warning above. Finally, note that you could use ExportCommand with your exporter, by calling *configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(ILayerExporter.CONFIG_ATTRIBUTE, new YourExcelExporter())*, where YourExcelExporter is a ILayerExporter.

Comment: Yeah I mean.. I guess my way wasn't the best. I kinda looped through the columns and facts then just pushed each val to a cell for excel.. Not sure if that is "bad" but it was the only way I thought to do it. It worked though.

Answer (score 1):

NatTable comes with an Excel Exporter based on Apache POI already. You need to add the POI extension from the NatTable project to your project for this.

Doing this gives you the opportunity to use the HSSFExcelExporter which produces a valid Excel file (the default ExcelExporter simply creates a XML format) and comes with additional configuration possibilities.

```
configRegistry.registerConfigAttribute(ExportConfigAttributes.EXPORTER, new HSSFExcelExporter());
```

Comment: To me, "powerful" does not seem like a neutral statement. It is okay to make opinionated statements on stackoverflow, but if it involves you product, you must [disclose your affiliation with that product](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior).

Comment: Sorry, I didn't wanted to advertise NatTable. So I remove the word from my answer.